# Laravel: How to get status of mass update that any of the value is updated or not?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, sql-update, laravel-collection

I am updating the status details of a few users using the below code is there any way I can get are there any changes made by this update.

```
$jobApplications = $job->jobApplications()->whereIn('user_id', $request->user_id)->update([
    'status' => $request->status,
]);
```

**Edit:** As per the suggestion from @lagbox

```
$jobApplications = $job->jobApplications()->whereIn('user_id', $request->user_id)->where('status', '!=', $request->status)->update([
    'status' => $request->status,
]);
```

Now I can check `$jobApplications` which will return the number of rows updated by the above query.

Comment: This may depend on the DBMS but the result of `update` should be the number of rows that where actually changed at least for MySQL

Comment: I am using MySQL, currently, I have only a row of data on there, even when I am performing this operation without any change it's giving me 1 as result.
Are there any hack to perform isDirty() or wasChanged() methods?

Comment: `isDirty` and `wasChanged` wouldn't help since you are not calling `update` on the Model, you are calling `update` on the Builder which will doesn't involve filling any model with data

Comment: perhaps you could add another where condition to this: `where('status', '<>' $request->status)` ... only update rows where the status would actually be changed by the update, then you could use that returned count as that would be only rows that were actually changed to this new status

Comment: @lagbox I didn't think that way, I will try that. Thank you